# Linux How can I obtain more details about my hardware 56k modem?

Tags: linux, modem, xubuntu

I'm using xubuntu and in my laptop hp 6730b I have a 56k modem but I don't know brand or manufacturer. Looks like it doesn't run in linux but would like to see more info about 
the device.

Any sugestions?

Already used:

```
lspci -Vvv | grep -i modem 

lsusb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `lspci` without the `grep` just in case it is not recognised as a modem (which is likely). Alternatively:

1. [ScanModem](http://linmodems.technion.ac.il/packages/scanModem.gz) is specifically designed to detect modems under Linux and help you configure them. See [here](http://linmodems.technion.ac.il/#scanModem) for more information.
2. `hwinfo`

   > hwinfo is used to probe for the hardware present in the system. It can be used to generate a system overview log which can be later used for support.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hwinfo
   ```
3. `lshw` and/or `lshw-gtk` (GUI)

   > lshw is a small tool to extract detailed  information  on  the
   >      hardware  configuration  of  the  machine. It can report exact
   >      memory configuration, firmware version,  mainboard  configura‐
   >      tion,  CPU  version and speed, cache configuration, bus speed,
   >      etc. on DMI-capable x86 or IA-64 systems and on  some  PowerPC
   >      machines (PowerMac G4 is known to work).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lshw lshw-gtk
   ```
4. The wealth of information available over at [linmodems](http://linmodems.technion.ac.il/).

Comment: I would suggest: Look at the device. Open it, look for chip names. Google those.. --- Which of the commands detected the modem?

Answer (score 1):

The HP6730B I've seen had LSI (nee Agere nee Lucent) HDA winmodem inside.

so try `lspci | egrep -i '(lsi|agere)'`

Comment: That only gave me the firewire information.
 lspci | egrep -i '(lsi|agere)'
86:02.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 (rev 70)